# java.io.NotSerializableException Issue

Tags: java, serialization, javafx

I am trying to send the following but I get the following error below. TableUser implements serializable but it seems that the issue is the the FXCollections, but I don't know how to serialize that.

Here is the TableUser class.

```
package application;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class TableUser implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username = "";

    public TableUser(String name) {
        this.username = name;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String user){
        username = user;
    }

}






//NOT apart of TableUser - This is the code that isn't working
private static ObservableList<TableUser> clientList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 

Object[] data = new Object[2];
        data[0] = "CLIENTS";
        data[1] = clientList;

        for(int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++){
            clients.get(i).sendData(data);
        }


//I don't know if this helps but here is the sendData method
protected void sendData(Object[] data){
        try {
            oos.writeObject(data); //ServerMultiClient.java:286
            oos.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


//This is from the Client application that is also part of the issue
if((fromServer = (Object[]) ois.readObject()) != null){ //Controller.java:109


java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at application.ChatRoomController$2.run(Controller.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at application.ServerMultiClient.sendData(ServerMultiClient.java:286)
    at application.ServerMultiClient.run(ServerMultiClient.java:236)
```

Comment: Just in case you haven't tried it, xmlEncoder works with observable lists.  I do encode them into zip files for size and maybe speed.  You may have to change the private static, I don't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `ObservableListWrapper` is not serializable you could try looping through your `TableUser` objects, and adding them one by one to `data`

Something like this:

```
Object[] data = new Object[clientList.size()+1];
data[0] = "CLIENTS";
int counter = 1;
for(TableUser tu: clientList) {
    data[counter] = tu;
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `NotSerializableException` is thrown when an object that is trying to be serialized has not implemented the `Serializable` class. In your case, since it is telling you that `ObservableListWrapper` is not serializable, I would infer that `clientList` is not serializable.

Instead of using a JavaFX `ObservableList`, you can use a list, such as `java.util.ArrayList`, which happens to implement `Serializable`.

Comment: In order to have to table update it has to be an Observable list. :\

Comment: You can use `FXCollections.observableList(List)` to convert a list to an observable list.

Comment: @thatJavaNerd I use `FXCollections.observableList(List)`, but it doesn't update as "true" ObservableList would update. It looks like it waits for another event to happen, and then it updates.

Comment: But the data written to disk (so the data in a file on disk) is not 'Observed' you just have to transform it form FXCollections.observableList <---> ArrayList<Object> at reading / writing time